# Split Column into Unknown Number of Columns by Delimiter Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to split a column into multiple columns based off comma/space seperation.

my dataframe currently looks like

```
    Item                                          Colors
0   ID-1                                          Red, Blue, Green
1   ID-2                                          Red, Blue
2   ID-3                                          Blue, Green
3   ID-4                                          Blue
4   ID-5                                          Red
```

I would like to transform the 'Colors' column into Red, Blue and Green like this:

```
    Item                                           Red  Blue  Green
0   ID-1                                           1    1     1
1   ID-2                                           1    1     0
2   ID-3                                           0    1     1
3   ID-4                                           0    1     0
4   ID-5                                           1    0     1
```

I really have no idea how to do this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can using [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
pd.concat([df,df.Colors.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')],1)
Out[450]: 
   Item          Colors  Blue  Green  Red
0  ID-1  Red,Blue,Green     1      1    1
1  ID-2        Red,Blue     1      0    1
2  ID-3      Blue,Green     1      1    0
3  ID-4            Blue     1      0    0
4  ID-5             Red     0      0    1
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks! Any ideas on how to make this perform well on larger datasets?

Comment: @christfan868 I think you can do with chunk ,. split your df into couple of dataframe, then doing the process above , then concat together