# How to split one column in a list into new columns when each list may have different number of members?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

So I have a dataframe in pandas with many columns.

One column has a list with strings deliminated with [u'str',] as shown below. There aren't equal number of strings in each row.

```
column x
[u'str1', u'str2', u'str3']
[u'str4', u'str1']
[u'str5', u'str7', u'str8', u'str9']
```

I want to create new columns in the dataframe called column x-1, column x-2 up to x-n

How do I:

1. Figure out how many new columns I need (i.e. how many members the biggest list has?)
2. Create that many columns using the nomenclature mentioned.
3. most importantly: split the strings into new the columns, only leaving what's between the single quotes (i.e. lose the u, the ', and the comma)

[image: attempted code]

Comment: Found a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069693/split-column-into-unknown-number-of-columns-by-delimiter-pandas

Answer (score 3):

If "column x" is the column of lists, you can pass the column as a Series to create a new DataFrame.

```
df['column x']
0    [a, b, c]
1          [d]
2       [e, f]
dtype: object

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    df['column x'].tolist()).rename(lambda x: 'x-{}'.format(x + 1), axis=1)
df2

  x-1   x-2   x-3
0   a     b     c
1   d  None  None
2   e     f  None
```

To add these columns back to `df`, use `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2, axis=1])
```

Comment: I get error 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: @Sharkfan1781110 Please copy the code instead of typing it out. You didn't type it out properly.

Comment: ok so that error went away but now it is still in one column. Where do we define the deliminator?

Comment: @Sharkfan1781110 Run `df['column x'].head(5)` and post the output in your question, or else I cannot help.

Comment: remember from original post u'str3' needs to go to str3

Comment: I mod the question. Thanks for the help. As you see, pretty new here. Trying to figure out how to get help best.

Comment: @Sharkfan1781110 Please do one last thing. Show me the output of `df['column x'].head(5).tolist()[0]`.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Ended up going to bed. I have now updated the post. Thanks again in advance. I think what I'm stuck at now is where to include the deliminator needed. Your suggestion may work once we can specify how to separate each row of the dataframe around u'str'

Comment: @Sharkfan1781110 sir, please take a look at the output. Not once have you hinted they were strings. I've assumed they've been lists all this time because that's what you've lead us to believe. What do I do now?

Comment: I apologize. As I mentioned new to programming. I'm going to make many mistakes. Thank you for trying to help. My situation still stands. The goal is to divide the data on the deliminators mentioned as mentioned. Your solution is close.

Comment: @Sharkfan1781110 as a preliminary step try doing "import ast; df[col] = df[col].apply(ast.literal_eval)" and then run the code in my answer?

Comment: I think I found my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069693/split-column-into-unknown-number-of-columns-by-delimiter-pandas

Answer (score 0):

So the exact code to this question is:

```
df_test['actors_list'] = df_m.actors_list.str.split('u\'') #splits based on deliminator u' (the \ is the escape character)
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame(
    df_test['actors_list'].tolist()).rename(lambda x: 'actors_list-{}'.format(x + 1), axis=1)
df_test2
```